# Bind function to the onClick on other scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to bind a function to the anchor `onclick` attribute. I'm not using the traditional jQuery's bind/live/on/whatever because I have some other scripts stopping the events propagation (it sucks, I know).

To bind the function to the `onclick` attribute I'm passing a JSON object to a module like this:

```
function foo() {
  alert('foo')
}

$('document').ready(function() {
    var options = {
        opt1: 'fooID',
        opt2: 'barID',
        json: mightyJSON,
        actions: [
            { url: 'contact/_id_/edit', text: "Edit", iconPath: 'edit.png' },
            { url: '#', onClick: foo, text: "Delete", iconPath: 'delete.png' }
        ]
    };

    var trolol = myModule.configure(options);
});
```

As you can see the function named "foo" is passed via the `onClick` property of the JSON. The function is defined above the object.

In `myModule` I'm creating the anchor tag like this:

```
var buildLinks = function(objectID)
{
  var linksNbr = actions.length;
  var link, cssClass;

  for (var i = 0; i < linksNbr; i++)
  {
    // Adding the object ID to the URL
    link     = actions[i].url.replace('_id_', objectID);
    cssClass = actions[i].cssClass || '';

    var $link = $(document.createElement('a')).attr('onClick', actions[i].onClick)
                                              .attr('href', link)
                                              .attr('title', actions[i].text)
                                              .addClass(cssClass)
                                              .text('foo');
  }

  return $link.html();
};
```

The thing is, as you can expect 'foo' is executed when the script is parsed and only there. The `onclick` doesn't even work after.

I can pass it like this `onClick: 'foo()'`. The `onclick` works but it's also executed at parsing and it's, in my opinion, very ugly.

I'd like to still be able to pass it like this `onClick: foo` but working correctly (i.e. not being executed at loading but only when clicking.

It has to work with jQuery 1.4.4 unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, could you please post this with an html that we can try this on ? or could you post a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ ? It's easier to code then and there and give you a solution :)

Comment: do you really need to pass around the `.html()`, and not just the created element?

Comment: How about passing it as [actions[i].onClick]()

Comment: Why not look into delegating the event, since they're all `a` elements, you could give them a default class like `linkDelegatorClass` and check for that class if you delegate the event... seems to me to be the most efficient way to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
var $link = $('<a></a>',{
    href : link,
    title : actions[i].text,
    'class' : cssClass,
    text : 'foo',
    click : actions[i].onclick
})
return $link;
```

Then use one of these ([1](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/),[2](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)) functions to insert the node, which is the html with events.

---

for the propagation issue i would do something like this:

html `<a href="#no" ....>text</a>`

js `$('a[href="#no"]').live('click',function(){ return false; });`

This way whenever the href is pointing to `#no` the event is eventually propagated

Comment: I managed it to work by inserting the final elements with `.append()`. I was initialy using a HTML string because I couldn't find a better way to insert it in a cell of dhtmlxGridObject. Now that I'm using `.append()` and not a string `click()` is working right.

Answer (score 0):

1. if at all possible, return the element, and not its `.html()`
2. having done that, don't use `.attr('onclick', ...)` when you've already got a function reference, use `.prop`, or even just `element.onclick = ...`

e.g.

```
$link = $('<a>', {
    href: link,
    title: actions[i].text,
    'class': cssClass,
    text: 'foo'
}).prop('onclick', actions[i].onClick);
```

Comment: or `.click` or `.on("click")` or `.attr('click', ref)` (calls `.click` implicitly) :P

Comment: OP said he can't use `.on`.  I note he's also serialising the element instead of passing it, which will break setting the handler as a property :(

Comment: He said that something is stopping propagation, in that case it wouldn't matter what he used. If some `.attr("onclick"` works then the normal way must work as well.

Comment: onclick works, not the .on/.click/.delegate as I said. I cannot use `.prop()` because I'm stuck with jQuery 1.4.4 :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/7f9mC/). If this approach is fine, you could as below set onclick on jquery's raw element, like this:

```
$link[0].onclick = options.actions[i].onClick;
```

Comment: It is working but I'd like to know why I need to use the raw `onclick` attribute and why it doesn't fire "foo" while it does with jQuery `attr`?

Comment: My guess would be that jquery's function "attr" executes the function in hopes of getting a string back (because it expects a string), while the example above just declare a reference to your function.

Comment: @koskoz: the attribute has little or nothing to do with how JavaScript/jQuery works: the attribute is a property of the DOM element, not a JS object, so a function JS function reference can't be  an html attribute, only its name can be set as an attribute. The approved answer sets the event handler in JS only, not by setting a node attribute, that way you can use function references. Alternatively, jQuery offers the `.prop` method, and jQ does the binding for you

Comment: this doesnt really solve anything but the way the node is inserted... because it doesnt use `$link.html()` (which should return a string with "foo" btw) which is exactly what Alnitak and myself tried to explain...

Comment: I'd like to use user338128 or Alnitak answers but I can't. I don't have `prop` available nor live/delegate/on. I keep saying it...